# Checking Obj Id value before pushing into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays of objects. I need to push the objects from one array into another, but I need to check the obj Id before I do so. If the id is already in the main array (songDatabase), is there a way to increment the obj Id instead of overwriting or having duplicate ids?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
onst songDatabase = [{ songId: 1, title: 'Drive', artist: 'The Cars', },
                     { songId: 2, title: 'When Doves Cry', artist: 'Prince', },
                     { songId: 3, title: 'Butterfly', artist: 'Crazy Town', },
                     { songId: 4, title: 'The Way I Are', artist: 'Timbaland', },];

const songList = [{ songId: 5, title: 'Save a prayer', artist: 'Duran Duran', },
                  { songId: 1, title: 'Sunday Blood Sunday', artist: 'U2', }]; 

function checkSongId(songIdCheck) { 
  for (let i = 0; i < songDatabase.length; i++){  
    songIdCheck = songDatabase[i].songId; //read the songId from songDb
    console.log(songIdCheck); //log each songId
  }
    if(songIdCheck === getNewSong(songList.songId)) { //check if the songId is already on the songDatabase
      songIdCheck =+ songIdCheck;
    } else {
      songDatabase.push(songList); 
    }
    // console.log('song already on the DB');
  return; 
}

function getNewSong(songId, title, artist) {
    for (let x = 0; x < songList.length; x++ ) {
  songId = songList[x].songId;
  title = songList[x].title;
  artist = songList[x].artist;  
}
  return {songId, title, artist}; //only returns the last songList Object
}

console.log(checkSongId());
console.log(getNewSong());
```

I was hoping to see all the songs into the songDatabase with unique ids, but I can't make it work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your intent with incrementing the song id?

Comment: you're doing =+ when it is += to increment

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, I have updated the code above and included both arrays. The intend is to make sure the object ids are unique. Both arrays have an obj with a songId: 1. I need to increment the Id before pushing into the main array.

Comment: Are you assuming incrementing the id will make it unique? Why not generate a GUID type of id for each song?

Comment: I know the index for the array is unique. I thought incrementing the obj id would make it unique. How do I go about generating a GUID type of id? I'm new to JS.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach may be to filter the new array to only songs that are not already there in old song array and concat two arrays. you could write it back to oldSongArray too if that is the need

```
let oldSongArray; //existing db
let newSongArray; //new db

let updatedSongArray = oldSongArray.concat(newSongArray.filter(_song => !oldSongArray.find(song => song.songId === _song.songId)))

// oldSongArray = updatedSongArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you're trying to increment the Id `songIdCheck =+ songIdCheck;` Change `=+` to `+=`. Thats how you correctly increment a value.

And in your second function you're returning one object. Which is the last object in the loop. To show all objects you can create an array and push an object each time you loop like this :

```
function getNewSong(songId, title, artist) {
let arr = []; 
    for (let x = 0; x < songList.length; x++ ) {
  songId = songList[x].songId;
  title = songList[x].title;
  artist = songList[x].artist; 

  arr.push({songId, title, artist}); 
}
  return arr; //only returns the last songList Object
}
```

Comment: I tried your aproach but I get the entire array, instead of each object:
0: Object { songId: 1, title: "Drive", artist: "The Cars" }
1: Object { songId: 2, title: "When Doves Cry", artist: "Prince" }
2: Object { songId: 3, title: "Butterfly", artist: "Crazy Town" }
3: Object { songId: 4, title: "The Way I Are", artist: "Timbaland" }
4: (4) […]
0: Object { songId: 5, title: "Save a prayer", artist: "Duran Duran" }
1: Object { songId: 6, title: "Shelshok", artist: "New Order" }
2: Object { songId: 7, title: "New ", artist: "U2" }
3: Object { songId: 1, title: "Sunday", artist: "U2" }

Comment: Loop through that array with arr.forEach and log every single object inside that array out